# RefrenceError: Property 'Proxy' doesn't exist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-hermes

Everything is fine while I'm in debug mode. But when I Stop Debug Mode I get the following Error:

> RefrenceError: Property 'Proxy' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes

[image]

Comment: what . does stop debug mode means? and what is proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2020-01-06, Hermes explicitly [does not support Proxy](https://github.com/facebook/hermes/blob/master/doc/Features.md):

> ### Language Features in Hermes
>
> Hermes plans to target ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), with some carefully considered exceptions.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Excluded From Support
>
> Reflection (Reflect and **Proxy**)
>
> [...]

You can follow [facebook/hermes #33](https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/33) for updates on this issue.

It works in "debug" mode because this mode runs JavaScript in V8 on the host, rather than in Hermes on device.